# Como ordenar uma lista com valores inteiros e textos em Scala?

Tags: scala

Tenho uma lista de objetos e preciso ordená-la com alguns critérios diferentes. Por exemplo:

```
class Pessoa {
  val nome: String
  val idade: String
  val profissao: String
}
```

Depois terei uma lista disso preciso ordenar essa lista pelo nome, idade e profissão. Então pensei em algo como:

`pessoas.sortBy(pessoa => s"${pessoa.nome}${pessoa.idade}${pessoa.profissao}")`

O problema disso é que como **idade** está sendo concatenado com outras *String*s, ele está se comportando como *String* e não está ordenando do menor para o maior, que é ideia dessa ordenaçao.